# SignOut of claims authentication

Tags: c#, forms-authentication, claims-based-identity, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have successfully implemented claims authentication in to my project.

As shown here:

```
 var userCredentials = new[] {
                new Claim("UserId", userProfile.UserId.ToString()),
                new Claim("Username", userProfile.UserName)};

        var id = new ClaimsIdentity(userCredentials, "Forms");

        var cp = new ClaimsPrincipal(id);
        var token = new SessionSecurityToken(cp);

        var sam = FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule;
        sam.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(token);
```

Which is working correctly, the issue I'm trying to resolve is signing that user out, I have the following class which is called when the user presses Sign Out

```
 public static void SignOut()
 {
     FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
 }
```

Which didn't seem to log the user out, so I went on a google search and tried the following:

```
FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut();
FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.DeleteSessionTokenCookie();
```

Neither of them work either? what could I possibly doing wrong?

This is my config:

```
 <configSections>
     <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
     <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
</configSections>

<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
       <forms loginUrl="/User/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
</system.web>

 <modules>
  <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
</modules>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

*Update*

I've just tried the following:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Session.Abandon();

// clear authentication cookie
HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
cookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);

// clear session cookie (not necessary for your current problem but i would recommend you do it anyway)
HttpCookie cookie2 = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "");
cookie2.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie2);
```

And redirected to the FAQ page but still I can see links in the navigation which should only been shown if the user is Authenticated.

Answer (score 2):

Managed to get this working!!

I now use

```
var sam = FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule;
sam.DeleteSessionTokenCookie();
```

Then I do a redirect and it works as expected :)